# Remove __MACOSX folder and .DS_Store file from all zip's on a directory in Windows

Tags: windows, macos, batch-file, directory, zip

i've got a pretty big list of zip files on a certain directory, each one of them containing a __MACOSX folder and .DS_Store file inside them.
Is there any way i could run some batch to delete the folder and the file from every zip without having to decompress them first?
I'm not very fond with shell scripting, ad i've tried some commands to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you have a way to run the zip program and bash on Windows.

ie. using Ubuntu shell for windows 10 https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows

1. enable Ubuntu for windows
2. `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y zip`

Once you have a compatible environment

1. First backup your directory of zip files, in case this command doesnt work as expected on your system.
2. Second, if you are using bash and have the zip program installed, run the following commands.

`cd $directory_with_zips`

`` for file in `ls`; do echo $archive; zip -d $archive __MACOSX; done ``

https://superuser.com/questions/600385/remove-single-file-from-zip-archive-on-linux

Comment: Thanks a lot, i enabled bash on windows and it worked fine. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Hi No problem! If this worked for you, please mark the answer as accepted, so that other people with the same problem can easily find the right answer :)